# How to insert images and videos into SQLDeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Please let me know how to insert images and videos to table using SQLDeveloper.

Comment: http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-quick-tip-blobs-and-images/

Comment: thanks but how can i do this using command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.

You can insert images or videos into an Oracle Database. You'll need a database, and a table, and at least one column setup to store your media. One way to do this is with Oracle Secure Files and the Binary Large Object Types (BLOB)

Once they're in the table, you can retrieve and update them in the client tools and applications, including SQL Developer.